# Tangent Angle to Parametric Ellipse

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, parametric, angle, tangent-line

I have an ellipse defined by the parametric equation: $$(x,y)=(a\cos\theta,b\sin\theta)$$ In this example: $$a=45$$ $$b=15$$ $$\theta =20°$$ How do I calculate the angle of the tangent line?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The slope is 
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy/d\theta}{dx/d\theta}
     = -\frac{b\cos\theta}{a\sin\theta}.$$
With the particular values, one gets
$$-\frac{15\cos\frac{\pi}{9}}{45\sin\frac{\pi}{9}} \approx -0.915826.$$
This is the slope, so the angle to the positive $x$-axis is $\tan^{-1}(-0.915826) \approx -0.74149 \approx -42.4843^{\circ}$.

Edit: With this Mathematica code

```
Show[ContourPlot[x^2/45^2 + y^2/15^2 == 1, {x, -45, 45}, {y, -15, 15}, AspectRatio -> 1/3], 
Plot[15 Sin[20 Degree] - 0.915826 (x - 45 Cos[20 Degree]), {x, 0, 55}]]
```

I get the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Doesn’t this give the slope rather than the angle?

Comment: @ZachBoyd Yes, thanks.

Comment: 42 degrees? Huh ... the angle doesn't _look_ that steep to me ... am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think that in your drawing the angle is really $20^{\circ}$. It looks much bigger than that.

Comment: That's bizarre ... I'm using industrial-grade engineering CAD software in the screenshot, so you'd think it would be accurate ... but I'm not an expert by any means, so I'm probably using the mathematical constraints incorrectly or something (the line is "constrained" as tangent, etc.) Thanks a ton!

Comment: The problem here is that parametrizing by $\theta$ along the ellipse is not a constant-speed parametrization, and in fact $\theta = 20^{\circ}$ does *not* produce an angle of $20^{\circ}$ with the $x$-axis; it produces an angle whose tangent is $\frac{15\sin 20^{\circ}}{45\cos 20^{\circ}} = \frac{1}{3}\tan 20^{\circ}$. So you need to be clear as to what you mean when you say $\theta = 20^{\circ}$ --- do you mean the angle to the $x$-axis, or the $\theta$ in the parametrization?

Comment: Ahh, that makes perfect sense. And I'll have to account for that when I plug this into the engineering design anyway, since the software uses a similar method for plotting the ellipse. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome!